# Replacing special characters in filenames in Windows powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to move a bunch of files from a windows directory to a sharepoint, needing to rename file and directory names, that are not allowed on the target filesystem.

Most of what I needed to do the task I found here:
[Replacing all # in filenames throughout subfolders in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647934/replacing-all-in-filenames-throughout-subfolders-in-windows)

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*`#*" -Recurse |
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '#','No.' } -Verbose
```

The solution provided by evilSnobu worked like a charm for these characters ~, #, %, &

The other characters not allowed on sharepoint are supposedly: +, *, {, }, \, :, <, >, ?, /, |, “

I am not exaxtly sure which ones are allowed on the source windows filesystem in the first place, but the "+" is and apparently a lot of filenames have that character in them.

For those I get an error from PowerShell saying that it invalidates the regular expression. This is unfortunately true for using the character or excaping it with the equivalent ascii code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*`+*" -Recurse |
>> Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '+','_' } -Verbose
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Any idea on how to deal with those?

Thanks Tim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip illegal characters before trying to save filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066783/how-to-strip-illegal-characters-before-trying-to-save-filenames)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the list that you are not certain of, they are all prohibited *except* `+`, `{`, `}`. To escape characters in regular expressions, use `\`, e.g., since `$` is the end-of-string anchor regexp, use `\$` to match a literal `$`. Alternatively, instead of `$name -replace '+','_'`, you might consider `$name.replace("+","_")`, which does *not* use regexp.

Comment: escaping the "+" worked like a charm, thanks so much.

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*`+*" -Recurse |
>> Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\+','_' } -Verbose

Answer (score 9):

My current way of cleaning file names/paths is to do this:

```
$Path.Split([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -join '_'
```

This uses the .NET function for current OS invalid characters (since .NET now runs on more than just Windows). It will replace any invalid characters with `_`.

Comment: such an easy solution :) Worked like a charm !

Comment: This is very useful to know! Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 1):

```
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\+','_' } -Verbose
```

So marvelous to solve my problem when I wanna reduced my "filename (1)" to "filename".
I simply modify the script to:

```
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\(1\)','' } -Verbose
```

It does really tackle the troublesome manual labor.